# Unable to Initialize WebDriver Chrome and all the tests are failing

Tags: c#, azure, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, remotewebdriver

I recently upgraded Chrome Browser Version to 78, Selenium Web Driver version to 3.141.0 and Selenium Chrome Driver Version to 78.0.3904.7000.

When i ran my tests on Remote Machine through Azure pipeline, all my tests are failing because of bellow failure. Please suggest how to handle this

> OneTimeSetUp:
>   Automation.Test.Framework.Models.Exceptions.AtGenericException : Error
>   initializing WebDriver Chrome
>   ----> System.InvalidOperationException : Driver does not support manipulating HTML5 web storage. Use the HasWebStorage property to test
>   for the driver capability

Answer (score 0):

Since Chrome 75, the default setting of the w3c spec compliance has switched to true.
However the C# binding only passes the option if it is set to true (assuming the deafult to be false).
This means we cannot set it to false at all with the current stable C# binding.

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/7521

Comment: Hey Hendrik - I would like to encourage you to reproduce important bits of the GitHub issue into your post itself. This will help the asker as well as the community to understand your answer easily. In due course, hyper-links can also become dead if target URL has changed. Hence people don't appreciate link-only answers on stackoverflow. I hope you'll understand and edit  your answer accordingliy.